# How to make recurring payment from one account to multiple account using Paypal (For IOS)?

Tags: ios, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-adaptive-payments, recurring-billing

We can complete parallel payment by Paypal MPL (Mobile payment library) - Called **Adaptive Payment** using [Paypal](https://github.com/SeraphimSerapis/paypalguide#adaptive-payments)

and i didn't found any other way to complete adaptive (parallel) payment with recurring feature.

If anyone can help then it will be great help.

i don't have any idea to do so using bellow Api's.

- Braintree
- express checkout

if this api's are usefull then please inform.

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: Chintan!, there is no such feature in MPL. might be possible through braintree paypal gateway (Web-based).